# How do you post data to joined tables - Using EF 5, ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, join, entity-framework-5

I am new to MVC 4 and up to this point I have been retrieving data from one table and saving back to the same table. Now I have data from joined tables and need to save back to the same joined tables. I created a new model and created the get controller but when I try to save I get an error. Any constructive help would be appreciated.

**Model**

```
 public partial class JoinClass
    {

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int EEID { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public int Points { get; set; }
        public string Programs { get; set; }
        public DateTime EntryDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime Quarter { get; set; }

    }
```

**Controller**

```
   public ActionResult Create()
   {               
       ViewBag.VBQuarter = new SelectList(db.Quarter2, "Id_Quarter2", "Quarter");
       ViewBag.VBEEID = new SelectList(db.Users2, "Id_Users2", "EEID");
       ViewBag.FK_Programs = new SelectList(db.Programs, "Id_Programs", "Programs");
       ViewBag.EntryDate = DateTime.Now;

       return View();           
    }

    //
    // POST: 
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(JoinClass joinclass)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
           db.JoinClass.Add(joinclass);
           db.SaveChanges();
           return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(joinclass);
    }
```

**View**

```
@model 2014_V4.Models.JoinClass

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
       <fieldset>
        <legend>Points</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">
          Quarter
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("VBQuarter")

        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
           User
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("VBEEID")      
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            Programs
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("FK_Programs", String.Empty)

        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
          Points
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Points)

        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
           Entery Date
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EntryDate, new {@Value = ViewBag.EntryDate, @readonly="readonly" })

        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: `when I try to save I get an error` - so maybe paste error content here?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not on my development machine today. But the error is basically "JoinClass in not part of Model"

Comment: Can you provide your View's code too?

Comment: @VahidND I added the view to my original question.

Comment: Do you use EntityFramework?

Comment: @KirillBestemyanov Yes, Entity Framework 5.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in constructor of JoinClass. You should not initialize virtual navigation properties collection with `new HashSet<T>`. Entity framework use its own collection type - `EntityCollection<T>`. You should not initialize navigation property collections at all.

PS: It is good practice to use special viewmodels with views and pass data from viewmodels to entity models explicit.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Can you show me an example of what you mean by using special viewmodels with views.